# Vanilla javascript draggable div within parent

Tags: javascript, draggable, color-picker

I want to achieve a draggable element in vanilla javascript.
I want to make a small circular div draggable within a square div.

To make myself a bit more clear, I do **NOT** want to:

- Create drag and drop,
- Use jQuery UI or any other library or plugin to achieve this, just vanilla javascript

I already have a few events for handling dragging:

`parent.addEventListener("mousedown", ..),`
`document.addEventListener("mouseup", ..)`
and
`document.addEventListener("mousemove", ..)`

My question is how can I keep the draggable inside the given bounds of its parent?

Reference: https://codepen.io/ChickenFlavored/pen/rNxRXGo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [getBoundingClientRect](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getboundingclientrect.asp) that gives DOMRect object(an invincible rectangle that encompass the object) with eight properties: left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height.

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();

var draggable = document.querySelector('.draggable');
var draggableRect = draggable.getBoundingClientRect();
```

You can get the mouse (X,Y) coordinates anytime by using `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`, so just check if they are outside the bounding rectable of `.parent` div if so then only update the `draggable` div's `left` and `top` properties

```
if( (e.clientX >= parentRect.left && (e.clientX+draggableRect.width <= parentRect.right)) &&
    (e.clientY >= parentRect.top && (e.clientY+draggableRect.height <= parentRect.bottom)) 
    //+draggableRect.height and +draggableRect.height accounts for the size of ball itself
){
            draggable.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
            draggable.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
}
```

Note that numbers increase down and towards right in graphics world

[image]
https://codepen.io/vsk/pen/PozVryr

**UPDATE**:
To fix the issue mentioned in comment use this

```
  if(/* mouse was moved withing red container's bounds*/)
  else{
    //if mouse went out of bounds in Horizontal direction
    if(e.clientX+draggableRect.width >= parentRect.right){
       draggable.style.left = `${parentRect.right-draggableRect.width}px`;
    }
    //if mouse went out of bounds in Vertical direction
    if(e.clientY+draggableRect.height >= parentRect.bottom){
       draggable.style.top = `${parentRect.bottom-draggableRect.height}px`;
    }
  }
```

And assign mousemove to document insted of the div container

Comment: Your code is truly amazing. I like how it is quite simple and short, however when you drag fast the draggable gets stuck at various positions before the boundaries. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, actually the root cause is that the 'mousemove' event fires only a finite number of times(due to performance reasons) but there's any easy fix for that - as soon as you notice the green ball go out of bounds you make it touch the red container's wall. https://codepen.io/vsk/pen/dyXLGVw

Comment: Thank you soo much! I really like how simple this code is but also very functional.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you could provide a code snippet to try to simulate what you want, a codepen url, codesandbox or similar.

I made this sample using what you provided : )

```js
let x = event.clientX - element.offsetLeft
const elementWidth = element.clientWidth
const fullX = x + elementWidth
const containerW = yourContainer.clientWidth
if(fullX > containerW){
  //If element will be out of container
  x = containerW - elementWidth // So it will be never out of container
}
element.style.transform = "translate("+x+"px, "+y+"px)"
```

Comment: I tried your code but it did not work I will post my code, my apologies for not having the code available earlier.